# Join Text Files Left to Right

Tags: cmd

I have a large number of text files (2000) each of 1 mb. What I am looking to do is join them in the easiest way possible, *however*, contrary to the already posted methods, I don't want to append one to the bottom of the previous one, I want to append it to the right (new column, tab) of the previous one.

For example, if there are 2 text files: 1 containing a `a` and other containing `b`:
I want

```
a        b
```

instead of

```
a
b
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any particular width that contents of each file should span in the final file?

Comment: If it helps, each text file is 2 columns wide, with the two columns separated with a tab, and I want each one back to back

Comment: How many lines are in each file?  How wide is the field of each line?  Batch files have limits and 2000 files with 1 character per line is already 3000 characters per line in the final output file.

Comment: Each file has 54676 lines and each cell has probably around 8 characters

Comment: The resultant line length is too long for batch using variables.  Maybe someone could use set/p to append to a file. VBscript is probably a better solution.

Comment: Ok thanks for trying! I'm not really sure how to do that so hopefully someone else will help out

Answer (score 0):

See how this works.  Put a literal TAB character where it says TAB.

It is probably going to take quite some time.  ! characters in the source may be an issue.

It deletes *.tmp files so move any out of the folder if you have them.

You can test it with half a dozen files in a folder.

```
@echo off
del *.tmp 2>nul
del "outputfile.txt" 2>nul
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir *.txt /b /on ') do (
set c=0
echo processing %%a
for /f "delims=" %%b in (' type "%%a" ') do (
set /a c=c+1
>>!c!.tmp set /p "=%%bTAB"<nul
)
)
for /L %%c in (1,1,54676) do (
if not exist %%c.tmp goto :done
echo adding file %%c of 54676
for /f "delims=" %%d in (' type "%%c.tmp" ') do (
>>"outputfile.txt" echo(%%d
)
)
:done
del *.tmp 2>nul
echo done
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I mean it looks like it does work how I wanted except that it is brutally slow. I ended up writing a VBA script in excel to merge 500 files as a time (due to memory limits) and then I will merge those files. I did it rather basically: Import text file, count last column, import next text file into last column +1. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it's writing to disk constantly so it will be slow.  You can accept the answer if you like.